# Supplementing Resource Controllers in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

I founding Laravel 5.1 documentation that if someone need to add extra route then Route::get could be possible. But I need this one. So is it possible. In my case this is showing error. TIA 
[link is here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers)

```
Route::post('institute/uploadProfilePicPost', 'Institute\InstituteController@uploadProfilePicturePost');
Route::get('institute/uploadProfilePicGet/{id}', 'Institute\InstituteController@uploadProfilePictureGet');
Route::resource('institute', 'Institute\InstituteController');
```

Comment: What is the error it is showing?

Comment: when i submit post to uploadProfilePicturePost method this is showing not supported error

Comment: Can you share the output of your `php artisan route:list`
See if institute/uploadProfilePicPost is there

Comment: of course these are there. Because I declared these what is here i mentioned